# Why FTP Handler not work with large files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

i have ftp handler that download files from ftp server directly to client browser :

```
public class FtpHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    string usname = "";
    //Connects to the FTP server and downloads the file
    private byte[] downloadFile(string FTPAddress, string filename, string username, string password)
    {
       byte[] downloadedData = new byte[0];

        try
        {
            //get the actual data
            FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + "/" + filename) as FtpWebRequest;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = false; //close the connection when done
            request.EnableSsl = false;
            request.Timeout = -1;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000;

            //Streams
            FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (Stream reader = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[262144];
                int read;
                while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }


            //Convert the downloaded stream to a byte array
            downloadedData = memStream.ToArray();

            //Clean up
            memStream.Close();
            response.Close();

            return downloadedData;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

It works fine with smaller files, but when to try download large file (e.g. 10MB) i have get error 504 Gateway Timeout Error !

please help me to resolve a problem

Comment: FTP Handler should work regardless of the file size.
It looks like a security problem.
I would check if the file import is somehow restricted on the server side.

Comment: @WalczakJakub ftp handler is not save file to server , if possible immediately transfer files from ftp to client the server not get response error

Comment: Is it possible that download speed is so low, that you get timeout error?

Comment: @WalczakJakub yes i get timeout error, i think client very time wait to response data from MemoryStream

Comment: Have you tried to check in how long it takes to perform each action in the method and compare it with the large and small file? e.g. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx